# Weak form for an equation with a first derivative?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

I know how to formulate the weak form of an equation with a second derivative, but am not sure for one with only a first order derivative. With the following equation
$$0=c\nabla N$$
I can multiply a test function $A$ to it:
$$0=c\nabla N \cdot A$$
and then integrate over it:
$$0=c\left(\nabla N, A\right) $$
Now I can either say that I am done, or rewrite it:
$$\begin{split}
0&=c\left(\nabla N, A\right)\\
&=c\left(\left(N, A\right) - \left(N, \nabla A\right)\right)
\end{split}$$

In terms of calculation: What is the more useful form? Both forms involve exactly one derivative, thus I assume that they are equal in terms of uncertainty. Is that correct?

Comment: When formulating an equation in weak form, multiply by a test function as you did, and integrate over it, and then you must take all the derivatives over to A, no derivatives on your function N may appear since they need not be defined. And when you do integration by parts, the boundary terms vanish since A is a test function.

Comment: @Luke: So the second version is the "more correct" version? Why do the derivatives on the function $N$ not have to be defined?

Comment: The sense of a weak formulation is that you can have solutions N of the equation that are themselves not differentiable in a strong sense.
We always have: If N is strongly differentiable, then the weak formulation implies the strong formulation.
But it entails more, also functions N that are only *weakly* differentiable, and to do so, we have to get all derivatives away from N. So yes, the second version is correct! (without boundary terms)